# Is there an easy way to find out what this site's on-topic and off-topic questions are?

Tags: feature-request, status-review, off-topic, allowed-topics, new-users

There is no quick and easy way to find what are the topics of Super User, nor what is off-topic

- The `superuser.com/tour`: Gives a very (and too) brief information in its first paragraph as to what is the site's topic (and thus also what isn't).
- In `superuser.com/help`: there is a questions mentioning a better description: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

To me this is not really visible: I went to search for an "About" link on the front page, then went to re-read the `/tour`, then to `/help`, but I didn't notice that one answer straight away.

Maybe someone could add a link to that question in the `/tour` first paragraph? Or maybe an even more visible "about" link somewhere in the top bar? Or at least in the bottom of the front page?

Or any suggestions you could have for a better way to make it known and visible (especially to new users).

Comment: Its about 3 links down - behind a see more link. For something a new user needs to find to use the site effectively that's kind of a pain, and unacceptable.

Answer (score 5):

What is currently written in [the tour](https://superuser.com/tour):

> Ask about...
>
> - Specific issues with computer software, hardware or networking
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
>
> Don't ask about...
>
> - Anything not directly related to computer software or computer hardware
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or require an extremely long answer
> - Videogames, consoles, or other electronic devices, unless they connect to your computer
> - Websites or web services like Google, Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - Shopping, buying or product recommendations
> - Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks

That's actually almost everything which is written in https://superuser.com/help/on-topic.

What's missing is:

- ON TOPIC: the specific nuance on "personal and home computer networking", although networking is mentioned, and corporate networks are said to be off-topic;
- OFF TOPIC: "asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation" - only 'product' is mentioned in the tour.

So, for a first information it actually looks fine to me.

Now, if only *everyone* would actually ***read*** it ...