Clarification of question's acceptability in advance
How can I check a question's correct place, acceptability and plausibility before posting it on Super User?
Is it possible to check the correctness of a question in advance here on Meta Super User? Or I send my question to some admin and the admin will indicate to me where is the right forum/place to put the question and how it should be edited and tagged so not to be blocked or closed?

So the question that I actually want to ask on Super User is:
When I use Firefox I regularly clear up the Firefox's cache by:

Menu -> Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Cookies and Site Data -> Clear Data -> Cookies and Site Data/Cached Web Content -> Clear

I was wondering is it possible to write a Bash script that would do this automatically every 2 minutes? Or is there any other way to bring Firefox to clear it's own Cache automatically?

I was thinking to give the next title to the question:

'Bash script for automatically clear Firefox's cache'.

And to tag the post with 'bash' tag.
Would such a question be allowed to be phrased in this way?

Meta Stack Exchange is the site for broader network questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168103/where-do-i-ask-where-to-ask

Have you looked at the help center? We're actually having some conversations about making it better so... if you have specific issues with finding it, letting us know would be useful. You can ask if something's on topic here too - or if further clarification is needed..
If you want a broader suggestion of sites that would work, meta.stackexchange.com does accept questions on where to ask questions on the topic

AH vaguely https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15143/is-there-an-easy-way-to-find-out-what-this-sites-on-topic-and-off-topic-questio but there's a bit of out of sight prodding (with a blunt stick) where opportunity presents itself. But lets be honest. A 14 year user of the site isn't going to see things the same as a new user, so encouraging people to constructively tell us where the system is falling short is useful. And starting conversations so we can bring this up to the community team with fresh eyes.

The TOPIC of this question is on topic on SuperUser, but in the state you have proposed it would be closed for not providing enough information and not demonstrating sufficient self-effort.
"I want to do X" is a common question, and it is commonly and rightly closed.
Prior to posting, ask yourself:

What research have you done on this subject prior to asking?
What have you tried so far?
Can I present my question clearly with the right amount of information necessary to accurately convey what I am seeking?

And then answer those questions and put that information into the question.
Specifically regarding scripting questions, the "what have you tried so far" bit means you must include code. We are not a script-writing service, which is not the same thing as "we will not help you with your scripting problems", but is "we won't write the entire thing for you". So, show us what you've got so far, and the things you've tried based on the research you've done, so we know what not to suggest as alternate solutions.
We also need to know the basics of the system you expect to run the code on, so the OS, at very least, and probably framework versions or details of other software involved in the solution.
So, topic? Yea, SU is the place. But you'll need to do some homework in order to get a good question that will be well-received here.
